# using pouchdb in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, pouchdb

I am trying to use pouch dB in a react js app. Please can you recommend any third party react wrapper available to use. Please can you share any code regarding this. The api should be able to perform the following operations:

1. access the pouchdb from react
2. put/delete/post/get documents
3. Sync data with couchdb at the remote database.
4. Work offline.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a 3rd Party React wrapper to use `PouchDB` with `React`. You can use the `PouchDB` js lib directly in your application and render the output using `React`.